# Can I use Google Actions to perform a task inside my app?

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I am building an expense tracking android-app. What I want is a feature so that user can add an expense by directly invoking google assistant, which add expense directly into my expense list in the app. Is this possible to implement using Google Actions? If yes, kindly guide me how to achieve this. If not, please guide me or provide hints for the alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Firebase for that purpose.

- Set up a Real-Time Database, modify the database values with google actions.
- Make your app code such that it listens for the database changes on firebase and updates with each new expense entry.
- Each user can have specific database entries for their expenses.